# How to check my home directory is encrypted in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I am using XUbuntu 12.04 and I want to be sure my home directory is encrypted. I have .ecryptfs in my home directory and other positive signs of encryption and had selected it during installation. But When I boot up computer and login as root in the console 1 without logging into my actual account, and try cd /home/myusername/ I can see all the files? Is this correct behaviour since the home directory will be mounted only when I login as 'myusername' or does root has access to all encrypted home directories?

Answer (score 19):

Easy!  Just use the [ecryptfs-verify](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-verify) command.

For instance:

```
ecryptfs-verify -h
```

*Full disclosure: I am the co-author and co-maintainer of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org), and happened to write the ecryptfs-verify tool, too ;-)*

Comment: Wow...the moment when the author answers your doubt!! Thanks a lot! And another doubt, how difficult is it for someone to crack it?